# Least squares fit with a trick

Tags: data-analysis, mean-square-error

Fitting a circle with least squares is easy once you get the trick for $c = r^2 - a^2 -b^2$ and you got a linear set of equations.

my problem is as follows:

$$z = \alpha x + \beta y + \alpha \beta$$

given a set of $x,y,z$, how can i fit(mse) the best $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is this "trick" you're referring to?  I surmise that you have in mind that the circle is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$.  That is equivalent to $x^2-2ax+y^2-2by=r^2-a^2-b^2$.  And this "trick" would apparently have us write $x^2-2ax+y^2-2by=c$.  But what is the "trick" and why would it make it easier?

Comment: OK, I posted some code. See if it is fast enough and gives what you want.

Comment: I fixed midnight bugs, added an explanation, and stated what is still needed. Any good ideas?

Comment: Should work like a clock now (optimized for 15 decimal digit floating precision). I'll be waiting for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll try to minimize $\|c_1x+c_2y+c_1c_2 z-t\|^2$ (I use the notation of the code below to make it easier to make comparisons). Note that if we had a free variable $c_3$ instead of $c_1c_2$, there would be no problem (at least, for non-degenerate data). So, it is tempting to consider the conditional optimization 
$$ 
f(C)=\|c_1x+c_2y+c_3 z-t\|^2=(QC,C)-2(S,C)+\|t\|^2\to\min
$$
$$
g(C)=2(c_1c_2-c_3)=(RC,C)-2(T,C)=0\,.
$$
The Lagrange multiplier theorem for quadratic forms is extremely nice: every local conditional minimizer is a global minimizer of $f+qg$ for some $q$.

However the global minimization is easy. First, we need to ensure that $Q+qR$ is non-negative definite (otherwise no global minimum exists). In our case, $\det(Q+qR)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $q$, so finding the initial admissible interval $[q-2dq,q+2dq]$ is not a problem. Next, the minimizer $C(q)$ is unique and given by 
$$
C(q)=(Q+qR)^{-1}(S+qT)\,,
$$
***provided that*** the matrix $Q+qR$ is non-degenerate. The minimum itself equals
$\|t\|^2-\left((Q+qR)^{-1}(S+qT),(S+qT)\right)=\|t\|^2-F(q)$. Note that this last expression is always a lower bound for the minimum in the original problem, so the true $q$ is easy to recognize: it should minimize $F(q)$ (the true minimal value must be  attained). The function $F(q)$ is convex, so its minimizing is a piece of cake (I just used the regular bisection algorithm below). Once we know $q$, we know $C=C(q)$.

It looks neat and clean except for "provided that". It turns out that the Lagrange global minimization problem is degenerate and the algorithm fails exactly if the original problem has multiple solutions. The ugly part of the code handles that case by moving in the direction of the possibly degenerate line to reach the correct ellipsoid surface (I preferred it to the paraboloid because of the stability issues; if there is no degeneracy, there is no real movement either).

```
import math;

real[] FF(real[] x,real[]y,real[]z,real[]t)
{

real 
xx=dot(x,x),xy=dot(x,y),xz=dot(x,z),
yy=dot(y,y),yz=dot(y,z),zz=dot(z,z),
xt=dot(x,t),yt=dot(y,t),zt=dot(z,t),
tt=dot(t,t);



real[][] 
Q={{xx,xy,xz},{xy,yy,yz},{xz,yz,zz}},
R={{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{0,0,0}},
S={{xt},{yt},{zt}},
T={{0},{0},{1}};

real ddd=xz*yz-xy*zz;
real q=ddd/zz,dq=0.4999999*sqrt(ddd^2+zz*determinant(Q))/zz;


real F(real q)
{
return (transpose(S+q*T)*inverse(Q+q*R)*(S+q*T))[0][0];
}

for (int k=0;k<25;++k)
{
if(F(q+dq)<F(q)) q+=dq; else if(F(q-dq)<F(q)) q-=dq;
dq*=0.5;
}


real[][] ans=inverse(Q+q*R)*(S+q*T);
real a=ans[0][0], b=ans[1][0], c=ans[2][0]; 

real[][] dirr={{(xy+q)*zz-xz*yz},{xz^2-xx*zz},{xx*yz-(xy+q)*xz}}; 

real C=F(q)+(transpose(ans)*Q*ans)[0][0]-2*(a*xt+b*yt+c*zt),
A=(transpose(dirr)*Q*dirr)[0][0], 
B=(transpose(S)*dirr)[0][0]-(transpose(ans)*Q*dirr)[0][0];
B/=A; C=sqrt(max(B^2-C/A,0));
real t1=B-C, t2=B+C, t=(t1^2>t2^2?t2:t1); 

ans+=t*dirr;
a=ans[0][0]; b=ans[1][0]; c=ans[2][0];

return new real[] {a,b,c,a*b-c};
}


real[] x={1,0,0},y={0,1,0},z={0,0,1},t={0,0,5};

real[] FF=FF(x,y,z,t);
write(FF);

real a=FF[0],b=FF[1];
real[] err=a*x+b*y+a*b*z-t;
write(dot(err,err));

pause();
```

Answer (score 1):

At the outset you want to minimise the expression

$$S(\alpha,\beta)=\sum \delta_i^2=\sum|z_i-(\alpha x_i+\beta y_i+\alpha\beta)|^2=\sum(z_i-\alpha x_i-\beta y_i-\alpha\beta)^2.$$

Differentiate with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to find the minima:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \alpha}=\sum2(z_i-\alpha x_i-\beta y_i-\alpha\beta)(-x_i-\beta)\overset{!}{=}0,$$

and

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \beta}=\sum2(z_i-\alpha x_i-\beta y_i-\alpha\beta)(-y_i-\alpha)\overset{!}{=}0.$$

This yields the *normal equations*:

$$\sum x_iz_i+\beta\sum z_i=\alpha\sum x_i^2+\beta \sum x_i y_i+2\alpha \beta\sum x_i+\beta^2 \sum  y_i+\sum\alpha \beta^2$$

and

$$\sum y_iz_i+\alpha\sum z_i=\alpha\sum x_iy_i+\beta\sum y_i^2+2\alpha \beta \sum y_i+\alpha^2\sum x_i+\sum \alpha^2\beta.$$

Now whether these have a (unique) solution is another matter completely. Why don't you use another constant $c$ rather than $\alpha\beta$?

Comment: This is what I was doing until now. The problem is once you estimate $c$ from the data, and it is not exactly $c =\alpha\beta$ but you have a small $\delta$, what do you do with the residue...

Comment: @Mercury if you give a bit more context maybe you can explain why you need $\alpha\beta$? Why not an independent parameter $c$?

Comment: I don't need $c$, I only need $\alpha$ and $\beta$. $c$ (or \alpha\beta$) is there just because the model dictates it.

Comment: @Mercury If you just include $c$ in the model it will be easy to solve.

Comment: the model is dictated by the physics of the system. For each input set $x,y$ I measure $z$. I know that the system behaves as $z=\alpha x+\beta y+\alpha \beta$, and I would like to estimate $alpha$ and $\beta$ from the measurements.

Comment: It might be still interesting to compare the results with $c$ and with $\alpha\beta$ in terms of the accuracy of $\alpha,\beta$ obtained numerically (introducing the Gaussian random error of various intensities, as always), if not out of practical needs, then out of sheer curiosity.

Comment: I just did it for fun. On 10000 runs with everything (except $z=(1,1,\dots,1)$ and $t$ derived from $\alpha,\beta,x,y,err$) Gaussian and with small to moderate noise $err$, the typical $\mathbb R^2$ Euclidean norm of the error in the vector $(\alpha,\beta)$ for my algorithm is about $5/8$ of that for the "$c$-method" and the probability that my method gives a better estimate is about $2/3$. Try yourself and see if you can confirm this. It is, however, still unclear whether there is an even better (the LSE is not a dogma!) coefficient estimator. So, in a sense, the question is still open :).